# How to detect face in python open cv?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, anaconda, haar-classifier

I am a newbie in python. I am working on a real time facial expression detection project. For the first module, my aim is to detect the face. 
Is there any way to detect face without using any predefined classifiers(Haar Cascade)?
Is there any algorithm to implement the Haar cascade in my own way?

Answer (score 0):

Ypu can use [Haar Cascades]:http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html
Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't want any classifiers. Is there any way to implement them or any other way to detect face?

Comment: i'm sorry mate. I dont know any other ways.